# Why is there no TryAdd that "filters" by both service type and implementation type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to add multiple services to our `IServiceCollection` that implement an interface (without adding each multiple times).  In other words they are unique by combining service type and implementation type.  This is similar to `TryAddScoped` or `TryAddSingleton`, but they only check for uniqueness on service type.

I use this to get a collection of them via something like:

```
var handlers = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IS3EventHandler>();
```

In other words, I'd like one implementation of TxtFileHandler that implements IS3EventHandler and one CSVHandler that implements IS3EventHandler.  And I'd like to call on the provider to return a collection that contains both of them.

I ended up writing a little extension method class as follows:

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection TryAddScopedByService<TService, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection) where TService : class where TImplementation : class, TService
    {
        if (!serviceCollection.Any(_ => _.ServiceType == typeof(TService) && (_.ImplementationType?.Equals(typeof(TImplementation)) ?? false))) return serviceCollection.AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>();
        return serviceCollection;
    }
    public static IServiceCollection TryAddSingletonByService<TService, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection) where TService : class where TImplementation : class, TService
    {
        if (!serviceCollection.Any(_ => _.ServiceType == typeof(TService) && (_.ImplementationType?.Equals(typeof(TImplementation)) ?? false))) return serviceCollection.AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>();
        return serviceCollection;
    }
}
```

The fact that I feel like I can't find this existing behavior in the MS code could mean that I am heading down an anti-pattern.  Does something like the above already exist and I'm missing it?  Am I doing something completely wrong?  Is this an antipattern?

Comment: Have you seen [TryAddEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions.tryaddenumerable?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-extensions-servicecollectiondescriptorextensions-tryaddenumerable)? I'd say it does what you want.

Comment: I did take a look @ that and thought it was also looking only @ the service type for uniqueness.  Thanks for helping me take a second look, it will do the trick.